# How to convert a functional component to a class component if I have these three lines?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have **SignupForm** component. It is functional component. But I need remake this component to class component.

I know that class component must have:

- line like this: `class SignupForm extends React.Component`
- method `render()`
- in my case`state`instead `useState`
- in my case method `setState`instead `setErrorMessage(res[0].message);`

But I still have:

1. `const history = useHistory();`
2. `history.push("/home");` in the method **onSubmit**
3. `const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({ /..  });`

And I don't know how to remake a functional component to class component through these three lines. How to do it?

Small part SignupForm.js:

```
const SignupForm = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState(null);
    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
      /........
      },
        validateOnBlur: false,
        /........
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({ 
          username: yup.string()      
           .required('This field is required'),
       /........
      }),  
     onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          try {
              const res = await apiFunction('api/auth/register', {
              /........
              });
              if(Array.isArray(res)){              
               setErrorMessage(res[0].message);  
              } else {
                 const token = res.token.token;   
                 localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);     
                 history.push("/home");
             }
          } catch(e) { 
              /........
          } 
       },  
    });

   return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
     <SignupInput
         /.......
         inputProps={{
           name:'username',
           value: values.username,
           onBlur: handleBlur,
           /.......
            }} error={errors.username} />
      <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>
     </form>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function wrapper around your class component. Thas allows you initialize hooks inside wrapper and pass it to your class component. Here is a code snippet of how that can be achieved.

```
function hooksWrapper(component) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const formikData = useFormik({ /* pass everything as in your code */ });

  return props => React.createElement(component, {
    ...props,
    history,
    formikData
  }, null);
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { history, formikData } = this.props;
    const {
      handleSubmit, 
      values, 
      handleChange, 
      errors, 
      handleBlur, 
      isSubmitting, 
      setSubmitting 
    } = formikData;

    ...
  };
}

export default hooksWrapper(MyComponent);
```

Comment: useFormik is hook as well. Call that line in wrapper and pass its return value through props.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if I understand correctly your question and why you need to rewrite functional component into classes.

In classes you cant use react hooks. You can mix class component that render functional etc.

But if you need rewrite this component you will need HoC (higher-order React component) component for this. This HoC component wrap your dummy component and pass items (history etc) as prop.

For example alternative for useHistory is HoC withRouter 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

So for formik withFormik()
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik

More info about HoC
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html